# Android studio error while building project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

`Android studio` is giving me following error while building project:

> C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Login-With-Google-Plus\Android-Login-With-Google-Plus\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\drawable\abc_btn_check_material.xml
>
> Error:(19, 59) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015').
>   Error:(20, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources :

```
 abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015
```

and

```
  abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000
```

are part of `DrawerActivity` but now are maked as private you must extend the activities from `DrawerAvtivity`

check this thread:
https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop/issues/12

> With the new support library versions, a lot of these default resource
>   references are now marked private. Which means you can no longer
>   reference them. Pass in your own Drawable resource to fix the issue.
>   For maintaining a Navigation Drawer across activities, make those Activities extend DrawerActivity.